# Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-paginate

I have written this query with pagination in it

```
$items = Item::select('items.*', 'sub_category_name', 'category_name', 'sub_category_slug', 'category_slug')
        ->join('sub_categories AS sc', 'sc.sc_id', 'items.sub_category_id')
        ->join('categories AS c', 'c.category_id', 'sc.category_id')
        ->where('items.is_active', '=', 1)
        ->where('sc.is_active', '=', 1)
        ->where('c.is_active', '=', 1)
        ->where('sc.sc_id', '=', $sub_category_id)
        ->paginate(1);
```

But it says

Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

But when I add `->groupBy('item_id');` it says

Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'books.items.item_name' isn't in GROUP BY

But when I do item_name in groupBy clause it says to groupBy the next column. Why?

Comment: What's the whole error message (including the query)?

Answer (score 26):

When you use aggregate functions like `MIN(),MAX(),COUNT() AVG()` you have to use `Group BY`

But in latest `MYSQL` u have to use all the columns in select as a group By too.

In your `config/database.php` turn off the strict mode.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

`'strict' => false` after that you can use group by on a single column too.

Answer (score 0):

You can comment ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY line in modes array

Comment: Where is that? Could you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: 'modes' is one of 'mysql' options (such as 'driver'), if you have it, you should comment ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in modes array